# Navigating back and forth multiple times makes the UIView to become black

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a UICollectionView, from this UICollectionView when a cell is selected a UITabBarController is pushed. 
Navigating back and forth multiple times (around 14 times), makes the UI in ViewController to become black. Here is a screenshot to show how the UI becomes after navigating back and forth multiple times https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fb80.jpg
Any suggestion why this can happen.

This is what I call for navigation to the view

The setup of View I navigate to:

```
public partial class NavigationView : UITabBarController 
{
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            SetupTabBar();
        }

        private void SetupTabBar()
        {
            //ios7 layout
            if (RespondsToSelector(new Selector("edgesForExtendedLayout")))
            {
                EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
            }

            UITabBar.Appearance.TintColor = _iosConstants.ApplicationColors.GreenTitleColor;

            UIControlHelpers.SetTabBarButtonTextAttributes(_iosConstants.IphoneProjectView.BarTextColor, "Helvetica Neue", 11.0f, UIControlState.Normal);
            UIControlHelpers.SetTabBarButtonTextAttributes(UIColor.White, "Helvetica Neue", 11.0f, UIControlState.Selected);

            NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = _iosConstants.General.TabBarGreenColor;
            NavigationController.NavigationBar.TintColor = _iosConstants.General.TabBarGreenColor;

            this.TabBar.Translucent = false;
            this.TabBar.ShadowImage = null;

            NavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden(true, false);

            SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

            TabBar.InvalidateIntrinsicContentSize();
        }
}
```

NavigationController.PushViewController(_ctrl, true);

Comment: You need to add some more relevant information on how you set up your view.

Comment: Also, is this happening on devices? As for what I see its a simulator for now!

Comment: @G.hakim On device is also happening

Comment: Can you try to replicate it in a new solution and share that code with us through Github or something? Technically this should not be happening, because the iOS SDKs can't have a bug like this, and Xamarin basically uses the iOS SDKs

Comment: Can you share a demo here to reproduce the problem?

Comment: The problem was that the UITabViewController was not the root controller, and as I found it's not correct to push an UITabViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue to my problem. The problem in the first place was that the UITabViewController was not the root controller, and as I found it's not correct to push a new instance of an UITabViewController.